# Change a field type programatically using VBA Access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have a routine that imports an Excel table, changes several column (field) names, adds an index and several new fields.  However, the indexed field imports from Excel as a Double and I would like to change it to Long.  This code snippet works all except for changing the type:

```
Set tdf = db.TableDefs(TableName) ' Modify the new MBDA List table
For Each fld In tdf.Fields
    Select Case fld.Name ' Change the name of specific fields
        Case "MBDA Piece ID #"
            fld.Name = "MBDA Piece ID"
            fld.Type = dbLong ' change the type from Double to Long
        Case ">>Grade Level"
            fld.Name = "Grade"
        Case Else
    End Select
Next fld
NumFlds = i
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the type of a table field once it's part of a table. Setting `fld.Type` only works when adding new fields to a table.

Your code probably gives "Error 3219: Invalid Operation" ?

But you can do it with DDL (Data Definition Language) SQL, with an `ALTER TABLE` - `ALTER COLUMN` statement:

```
db.Execute "ALTER TABLE [MBDA List] ALTER COLUMN [MBDA Piece ID] LONG"
```

Edit: Here's an overview of DDL data type names vs. DAO constants (e.g. `dbLong`): http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub vRunSetFieldType()

Call vSetFieldType("Reporting Period", "LONG")

End Sub

Sub vSetFieldType(strFld As String, strFldType As String)

Dim db As dao.Database
Dim tbl As TableDef
Dim fld As dao.Field
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
    If InStr(1, LCase(tbl.Name), "msys") = 0 Then
        For Each fld In tbl.Fields
            If LCase(fld.Name) = LCase(strFld) Then
                'Debug.Print tbl.Name & Chr(9) & fld.Name & Chr(9) & fld.Type
                strSQL = "ALTER TABLE [" & tbl.Name & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & fld.Name & "] " & strFldType & ";"
                Debug.Print strSQL
                db.Execute strSQL
            End If
        Next fld
    End If
Next tbl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Sub AlterDataType()
   Dim strSQL As String
   strSQL = "ALTER TABLE [myTable] ALTER COLUMN myColumnDbl memo"
   DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Sub
```